# Using JavaFX for making a Eclipse Plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, eclipse-plugin

I am planning to develop a rich set of plugins for Eclipse which would involve 3D Graphics rendering inside Eclipse.

Is JavaFX a good technology choice for developing a Eclipse Plugin?

Is there some other rich client technology that I am missing out on and which can be used to develop Eclipse Plugins (other than SWT and JFace)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse 4, the new major release of eclipse, (4.2 due this summer) is supposed to support non-swt frontends in RCP/Plugin development.
However I am not sure how far along is the work to support javafx rendering.

You can find some info on E4 + JavaFX on Tom Schindl's blog
http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2011/10/17/efxclipse-0-0-7-released/ and 
http://efxclipse.org/

Maybe Lars Vogel has also written something about this, I am not sure. Anyways Lars is IMO the best source on the internet when it comes to E4
http://www.vogella.de and 
http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse4RCP/article.html

Anyways, Eclipse 4 is the way to go/research if you need RCP without SWT. I do not think this is doable in Eclipse 3.x at all.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4

Answer (score 1):

I've just released a step by step tutorial how to use JavaFX inside an Eclipse View. See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial2

Comment: 404. Please include the content in your answer; external links rot.