# Eclipse: Is it possible to mix SWT and JavaFX based plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, javafx, eclipse-plugin

With Eclipse 4.x UI being abstracted by underlying rendering (SWT or JavaFX).

It is not recommended to use two technologies in one plugin ([Is it possible to embed a SWT Composite into a JavaFX scene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812360/is-it-possible-to-embed-a-swt-composite-into-a-javafx-scene))

**However, can Eclipse have both SWT and JavaFX based plugins?**

Related [Using JavaFX for making a Eclipse Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051629/using-javafx-for-making-a-eclipse-plugin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mixing UI toolkits is possible, but is really not a good idea. Each UI toolkit has its own event loop and you have to have a bridge between the two. These bridges are notoriously difficult to implement and even relatively stable implementations, such as SWT-to-AWT that enables SWT/Swing mixing, have many serious unresolved issues.

Eclipse 4.x modeled UI does not eliminate this issue.